# Processing multiple expressions using a stack in Java?

Tags: java

Writing a postfix expression calculator. I know want to add the ability to calculate an expression with more than 2 operands and more than 1 operator, where the answer for the first operation becomes the operand for second expression. For example:

10 6 + 5 -

The expression would be evaluated as:

10 + 6 = 16

16 - 5 = 11

After some research I have found that my best option would be to use a Stack, which is a data store I am not familiar with as someone that is new to Java. I would like the code to be read after the user has entered a certain character just as the program currently is. Any guidance would be very appreciated.

This is what I currently have.

```
    Stack nums = new Stack();

            nums.push(element1);
            nums.push(element2);
            nums.pop();
            nums.push(element4);
            nums.pop();
```

Comment: Really struggling to figure out how I would apply this to my current program and scenario.

Comment: I think I will be fine with the logic behind it, but how do I add the items to the stack that are taking from the scanner the user input?

Comment: Little bit of thinking with the old fashioned pen and paper and I think I've got it, thanks.

Comment: Slightly unclear on the "pop" part. I've added the two operands to the stack, when I reach the first operator this is where I get stuck.

Comment: How do I apply the operator? I'm storing answers in a variable called answer to use for another part of the program.

Comment: This is what I've got at the moment, could you tell me what's wrong?